# docker set iptables false, minikube start fails

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm having an error trying to have docker set iptables false when minikube start fails.

Below are my logs:

```
minikube v1.20.0 on Centos 7.6.1810 (amd64)
* Using the none driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Restarting existing none bare metal machine for "minikube" ...
* OS release is CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.20.2 on Docker 20.10.6 ...
! initialization failed, will try again: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH=/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.20.2:$PATH kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,Mem": exit status 1
stdout:
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.20.2
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks

stderr:
    [WARNING Firewalld]: firewalld is active, please ensure ports [8443 10250] are open or your cluster may not function correctly
    [WARNING Service-Docker]: docker service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable docker.service'
    [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
    [WARNING Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap
    [WARNING FileExisting-socat]: socat not found in system path
    [WARNING SystemVerification]: this Docker version is not on the list of validated versions: 20.10.6. Latest validated version: 19.03
    [WARNING Service-Kubelet]: kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables]: /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables does not exist
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error you included states that you are misising `bridge-nf-call-iptables`.
`bridge-nf-call-iptables` is exported by `br_netfilter`.
What you need to do is issue the command

```
sudo modprobe br_netfilter
```

and then ensure `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` is *set to 1* in your *sysctl*

```
cat <<EOF >  /etc/sysctl.conf
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
EOF
sysctl --system
```

This should fix your problem